# Add up the size of every image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add the size of every image, so it's kept in one variable. I have this so far:

```
var totalHeight;
var addHeight = $(this).height();

$('.img').each(function(i){
    totalHeight = totalHeight + addHeight;  
    console.log(totalHeight);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/dKjcc/1/

However, the console.log is reporting `NaN`. Would anyone know why?

Comment: `$('.img')` will find all element with `class="img"`... do you mean `$('img')`?

Comment: Sorry, nope, just using placeholder divs instead atm.

Comment: You need to initialize `totalHeight` to 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var totalHeight = 0;

$('.img').each(function(i){
   totalHeight += $(this).height();
});
```

Further explanation: the *this* you want use is the element that match the selector ".img". What you have now, var addHeight = $(this).height() is the (height of) global object window

```
console.log(this === window);
```

Read up on using keyword [*this* at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) or at [learn jQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `var totalHeight = 0;`

Comment: So does `var totalHeight;` become a string?

Comment: No, it is like doing `undefined + 10`. Try running that in the console of your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Going ths route you were originally going:

```
var totalHeight = 0;

$('.img').each(function(index, element){
    totalHeight = totalHeight + element.clientHeight;   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Plain JavaScript:

```
function heights(element)
{
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++)
  {
    sum += element[i].clientHeight;
  }
  document.write(sum);
  return sum;
}

var imageArr = document.getElementsByClassName('img');
heights(imageArr);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Try this    
 <pre><code>
    var totalHeight=0;
    var addHeight = $(this).height();

    $('.img').each(function(i){
        totalHeight = totalHeight + addHeight;  
        console.log(totalHeight);
    });
    </pre></code>
```

Comment: Sorry, this is just plain incorrect.  It does not address the fundamental problem with the original code, where `addHeight` is being set.